# How to select first node only in xslt

Tags: xslt, apply-templates

My XML provides me with multiple images assigned to different mmids:

```
<Mediendaten>
    <Mediendaten mmid="22404">
        <url size="original">A 22404 FILE</url>
        <url size="thumb">ANOTHER 22404 FILE</url>
    </Mediendaten>
    <Mediendaten mmid="22405">
        <url size="original">A 22405 FILE</url>
        <url size="thumb">ANOTHER 22405 FILE</url>
    </Mediendaten>
<Mediendaten>
```

My XSLT selects only the urls where size=thumb:

```
<xsl:template match="/Mediendaten">
<xsl:apply-templates select="Mediendaten/url">
</xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Mediendaten/url">
<xsl:if test="@size = 'thumb'">
<img width="280" border="0" align="left">
<xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
</img>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

HOWEVER, I only need the thumbnail from the first mmid (in this case 22404). I have NO control over the mmid value.

How do I stop my template so it only outputs the thumb file of the first mmid?

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Rather than using an `<xsl:if>` inside of your template, you can put that criteria inside of your template match: `<xsl:template match="Mediendaten/url[@size]">`. It will give the XSLT processor a chance to optimize, and simplifies the stylesheet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The simplest way is to change the template for `/Mediendaten`:

```
<xsl:template match="/Mediendaten">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Mediendaten[@mmid][1]/url"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The [@mmid] constrains the selection to child Mediendaten elements that carry the mmid attribute, the [1] constrains the selection to the first one of these.

P.S. Whoever designed the XML you are using hates you.  (Using the same name for both kinds of element now labeled `Mediendaten` is a dirty rotten trick; it makes everything you do with the data harder.  Try to figure out what you did to piss them off so badly, and make amends to them.  Just a word to the wise.)

Comment: Great answer. Thanks. Worked perfectly. And you're right: the XML is 'challenging'... We'll send them flowers and a good bottle of wine ;)

Comment: @RichardTinkler did you ever send it to them?

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Mediendaten[1]/url" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Somme commends.

First of all follow the suggestion from  Mads Hansen. Have a template which now how to handle "thumb" images.

```
<xsl:template match="Mediendaten/url[@size = 'thumb']" >
    <img width="280" border="0" align="left" src="{.}" />
</xsl:template>
```

Then if you like to output only the first thump image  (from Mediendaten in **document order**) use:

```
<xsl:template match="/Mediendaten">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Mediendaten[1]/url[@size = 'thumb']" />
</xsl:template>
```

But if the meaning of
*"HOWEVER, I only need the thumbnail from the first mmid"*
is not Mediendaten (with mmid) in document order, but  the from Mediendaten  with the smallest mmid. Try this:

```
<xsl:template match="/Mediendaten">
    <xsl:for-each select="Mediendaten">
        <xsl:sort select="@mmid"/>
        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="url[@size = 'thumb']" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```